# Constant management across assemblies

Tags: c#, constants

My team is trying to figure out the best way to manage centralized constants (Read-only static variables probably) across our custom assemblies.  We have built a processing architecture where assemblies are dynamically loaded into the runtime.  As data goes through our system, some assemblies write information to a dictionary that is then passed to another assembly that will read the data out and process it.  As our product matures and our customer needs different processing capabilities, we will need to add new data fields that will be written/read.  As of now we have our constants defined in our core dll, but this will not work long term because when we get a new piece of data we will have to recompile the core dll, and in doing so our test team will have to fully regression test the entire application rather than just testing the new functionality provided by the new assembly.  Were trying to figure out a way to add new constants and know what data is being written without having to recompile/deploy anything we don't absolutely have to.

We have considered two options:

1. Create a constants dll, which only holds the constants.  When we
   need new fields we add (never remove) them to the dll.  The down
   side of this is that a change to the dll still  affects the entire
   system, so there may be a need for full regression testing.
2. Have each assembly expose all of the fields that it reads/writes,
   and then during developer integration look for name mismatches.  For
   example Assembly1 writes (Field1, Field2) and Assembly2 reads
   (field1, Filed2), causing a mismatch of (Field1 vs. field1) due to
   case sensitivity on dictionary keys.  This would keep us from having
   a constants assembly, but it would require some additional code for
   mismatch verification, and seems to cause some bit of coupling.

Note:  when I say constants, I don’t really mean constant.  Depending on the solution we end up going with we will probably use read only static.

If anyone has done anything like this, or have any thoughts on a way to accomplish this I will appreciate your input.  Our underlying objective is to be able to deliver new functionality by only deploying the new assemblies.

Comment: What data do these constants hold?  Why do they need to be accessed from other assemblies?

Comment: The Dictionary is set up as a <string,string>.  They need to be accessed by different assemblies because each assembly does something specific.  For example one assembly will take incoming data from an xml document, and populate it into the dictionary.  Then another assembly will pull the data out of the dictionary to put it into a custom csv file.  Both assemblies need to know that they are accessing the "PrimaryAddress" field.  If that makes any sense.

Comment: Is there some compelling reason that these values need to be compiled in as constants?  What about creating a config file that holds the constants as key/value pairs, then having a "constants" DLL that just reads this data into a globally available Dictionary.   Then, you don't have to recompile when new constants are added, and regression testing can be limited to verifying that the values of the new constants don't interfere with the values of the existing constants.

Comment: I doubt there is a solution that can decouple source code changes from regression tests. On the other hand with a table-driven approach you could accomplish this because your assemblies would not need to change. The drawback is that you will need some kind of script-engine or on-site code generation and compilation.

Comment: There is no compelling reason to use constants other than making the code easier to write.  I.e. Dictionar[constantsDll.myCoolValue] = "blaaBlaaBlaa". Reading the information from a config file then loading the data into a global dictionary could work.  There just wouldn't be any compile time constraints (string that are being used) applied.  I realize this is a case of me wanting high levels of flexibility and high levels or rigidity.

Comment: @Means - does my DTO suggestion work for you?  That seems to me to provide both flexibility (each assembly defines their own classes, others just need the minimal base implementation) and rigidity (you ensure compile time type checking).

Comment: I had my colleagues take a look at the post and they noted that I am missing some information about our app.  We have a pluign app that runs as a service.  We get data in and send it through a series of processing steps.  Each of these steps reads or writes data, then that dictionary is handed off the next step.  The steps are defined by the user through a configuration interface.  Because of the plugin nature we don't know what data will be written to the dictionary until runtime.  What we want to know is that when a plugin writes the "Address" it will be called "Address" in the dictionary.

Comment: So you don't really care what data is in "Address"?  It can be a street number, or the full Address/city/state/zip string?  Or is the maximum superset of data known?  And does it matter on the end whether you have an Address or not - or even whether you *know* whether you have an address or not?  Or can you just get away with "For every key..."?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, this really sounds like you should be using DTO classes.  Rather than a dictionary with values

```
dict["PrimaryAddress"] = "123 Someroad St."; 
dict["Name"] = "John Doe";`
```

you should have an object

```
public class Address
{
    public string PrimaryAddress { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
....
new Address { 
    PrimaryAddress = "123 Someroad St.",
    Name = "John Doe",
};
```

For convenience, you can create a base class in your core library which defines some standard behavior for all the classes (for example, `public Dictionary<string, string> ConvertToDictionary()` for legacy use), and then each assembly can inherit from that to create their own objects.  Then the assembly that consumes them can either reference the generating assembly and treat it as the specific type, or it can just treat it as the base form and use the base functionality.

Comment: I get your throughts, but unfortunatly it wont work for us.  I added some clarifying comments above, but basically we have a series of plugin steps that read/write data to the dictionary.  The problem is we don't know what data is going to be in the dictionary because each plugin can wirte different data and the user configures what plugin is used at each step.  What we need is a way for each plugin (each plugin is a dll) to know that if "Address" is in the dictionary it will be under the key "Address", or if you are writing address data you do so in the "Address" key.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create one assembly that is referenced by all other assemblies across your process. (Note that I assume that there actually is only one process in your application).
This assembly will expose a class to hold these "constants". Let's call it a session.
Here is an implementation we use in one of our projects:

```
//Defined in Dll appshared.dll    
public static class MyApplication
{
    static AppSession appSession = new AppSession();
    public interface IAppSession
    {
        Object this[string key]
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    };
    sealed class AppSession : IAppSession
    {

        Dictionary<String, Object> _session = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        public AppSession()
        {
        }
        public Object this[string key]
        {
            get
            {
                Object ret = null;
                lock (_session)
                {
                    _session.TryGetValue(key, out ret);
                }
                return ret;
            }
            set
            {
                if (key == null)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException();
                try
                {
                    lock (_session)
                    {
                        if (value != null)
                            _session[key] = value;
                        else
                            _session.Remove(key);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception eX)
                {
                }
            }
        }
    };

    public static IAppSession Session
    {
        get
        {
            return appSession;
        }
    }

};
```

And you can use it as follows:

```
//In Dll A referencing appshared.dll   
MyApplication.Session["Const1"] = 1.0;//Set a global value

//In Dll B referencing appshared.dll    
double const1 = (double)MyApplication["Const1"];//Read a global value - const1 will have the value set by Dll A

//In Dll C referencing appshared.dll
MyApplication.Session["Const1"] = null;//Delete a global value;
```

You can of course store any kind of data you want. You can easily modify it not to be case sensitive.

We also have more a complex session object that can synchronize the values with configuration files so the "Constants" are stored across executions. However since you didn't mention you need such capability this simple class should work just fine for you.

Comment: There is only one process, but there is a new dictionary for each piece of data we process.  In your example above, it's the "Cost1" string we are trying to figure out how to manage across dlls, that way all dlls know about "Const1" with as minimal coupling as possible.  Or it's possible your example can do that, and I do not understand your example.

Comment: @Means That's exactly what this example does. The class above is defined in just one assembly but all assemblies that reference that assembly can access it and query it's content. I will make it clear in the answer